# Converting PHP MySql insert to Node-MySql Insert

Tags: javascript, node.js, node-mysql

In a journey to master `JS` I am converting an AJAX Login Registration system I have to JS / Node.js

I am confused on how to handle data from the form to the DB.

Currently I have 
Form Post to AJAX function which calls a php file at url then gets a response.

I am assuming I need to convert the php function to a js file and use node to make the insert but I am wondering if it would be better to rewrite the AJAX function to handle the insert because there is no need for php?

Or basically just change the url from calling a php file to calling a js file and then have the new js file do exactly what the PHP file was doing?

Form calls js ajax like this,

```
 <form class="form-signin" id="loginForm" onsubmit='registerUser();return false;'>
```

Then ajax function looks like this,

```
function registerUser(){


    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'actions/register.js',
        data: "username=" + $('#registerUsername').val() + "&password=" + $('#registerPassword').val() + "&email=" + $('#registerEmail').val() + "&task=register",
        success: function(response){
            console.log(response);
            if(response === 'Correct'){
                    $('.messageText').empty()
                    $('.messageImage').empty()
                    $('.messageText').append('Please check your email for a validation link.');
                    $(".messageImage").append('<img src="images/success.png" height="50" width="50">');
                    $('.message').slideDown(400).delay(10000).fadeOut(400)
                    $('#registerUsername').empty()
                    $('#registerPassword').empty()
                    $('#registerEmail').empty()
            }
            else if(response === 'utaken'){
                    $('.messageText').empty()
                    $('.messageImage').empty()
                    $('.messageText').append('That username is already taken.');
                    $(".messageImage").append('<img src="images/error.png" height="50" width="50">');
                    $('.message').slideDown(400).delay(10000).fadeOut(400)
            }
            else if(response === 'eused'){
                    $('.messageText').empty()
                    $('.messageImage').empty()
                    $('.messageText').append('That email address is already registered.');
                    $(".messageImage").append('<img src="images/error.png" height="50" width="50">');
                    $('.message').slideDown(400).delay(10000).fadeOut(400)
            }
            else if(response === 'nusername'){
                    $('.messageText').empty()
                    $('.messageImage').empty()
                    $('.messageText').append('Please enter a username.');
                    $(".messageImage").append('<img src="images/error.png" height="50" width="50">');
                    $('.message').slideDown(400).delay(10000).fadeOut(400)
            }
            else if(response === 'npassword'){
                    $('.messageText').empty()
                    $('.messageImage').empty()
                    $('.messageText').append('Please enter a password.');
                    $(".messageImage").append('<img src="images/error.png" height="50" width="50">');
                    $('.message').slideDown(400).delay(10000).fadeOut(400)
            }
            else if(response === 'nemail'){
                    $('.messageText').empty()
                    $('.messageImage').empty()
                    $('.messageText').append('Please enter an email address.');
                    $(".messageImage").append('<img src="images/error.png" height="50" width="50">');
                    $('.message').slideDown(400).delay(10000).fadeOut(400)
            }
            else{
                    $('.messageText').empty()
                    $('.messageImage').empty()
                    $('.messageText').append('There was an unknown error.  Please try again later.');
                    $(".messageImage").append('<img src="images/error.png" height="50" width="50">');
                    $('.message').slideDown(400).delay(10000).fadeOut(400)              
            }            
       }
    });
};
```

This is the php file the ajax function calls,

```
<?php

//Include files
require_once('../classes/class_login.php');

//Get post data
$username = $_POST['username'];
$password = $_POST['password'];
$emailAddress = $_POST['email'];

if ($username == ''){
        print ('nusername');
    }

else if ($password == ''){
        print ('npassword');
    }

else if ($emailAddress == ''){
        print ('nemail');
    }

else {  
    //Call register function
    insertUser($username, $password, $emailAddress);
}

?>
```

Is it safe to say I can just convert the php function to js and then change the url in the ajax function to call it?

If so where is a good reference to achieve this goal I am having trouble finding an example that closely refers to my situation.

Comment: If anyone would mind explaining why this question would get down voted I would appreciate that.

Comment: Yes definitely safe. you can go ahead. you have a large "else" statement in ajax response handler. So you can swap urls.

Comment: I did not downvote the question, but I guess the one who did did because of your last sentence "If so where is a good reference to achieve this goal I am having trouble finding an example that closely refers to my situation."

Comment: Thanks @bestprogrammerintheworld Why would that sentence call for a down vote? I genuinely would like to understand better so I don't get down voted as much.

Comment: @risyasin thanks for your response. So basically I would post the variables the same way I was but handle them with a separate js file? just add the posted variables to a  node mysql insert statement in the new file?

Comment: @NichoDiaz First of all you need to prepare your response in node.js, you can go with basic http object of nodejs but i don't advice that. Try Express.js for this task. spend some time with documentation. nodejs can exactly do the same job with php in your situation.